# XSLT1.0: Replace subsring value of occurence of attribute in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, attributes, substring

I have XML file (ISO 19115 metadata XML file) and I want to change part of value of codelist attribute in whole XML.
URL for whole XML file https://rpi.gov.sk/rpi_csw/service.svc/get?request=getrecordbyid&service=csw&version=2.0.2&outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&resulttype=results&elementsetname=full&id=https://data.gov.sk/set/rpi/gmd/00626031/170123074833

I would like to replace part of codelist value for all occurences:

Example:
INPUT:

```
 <gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="service">service</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
<gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="service">service</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
```

I tried this:

```
<xsl:param name="findText" select="'https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml'" />
<xsl:param name="replaceText" select="'http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml'" />

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$findText" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$replaceText" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But result is not what I expect. Replacement is OK but it doesn't keep elements/nodes - result of replacement is not an attribute. Structure and result is:

```
<gmd:hierarchyLevel>
    <gmd:MD_ScopeCode>http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCodeserviceservice</gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
</gmd:hierarchyLevel>
```

How can I Made it to keep elements structure?

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a free code-writing service; the idea is to try something, then if you get stuck, we can help.

Comment: Which part do you want to replace, with what? Your example does not amount to a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="@codeList">
    <xsl:attribute name="codeList">
        <xsl:text>http://standards.iso.org/iso/19139/resources/gmxCodelists.xml#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '#')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>    
</xsl:template>
```

---

To limit this to `codelist` attributes that have the specified URL, you could change:

```
<xsl:template match="@codeList">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="@codeList[starts-with(., 'https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml')">
```

Comment: This is the way too, but I doesn't need to replace all the codeList values, just codelist with value 'https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml'

Comment: @RadoslavChudý See the addition to my answer.